# How can node.js sockets be linked to a page so text typed when connected to sockets' port appears on page?

Tags: http, node.js

I'm familiarizing myself with node.js and after seeing Ryan Dahl's example where he builds a super-simple chat server, i decided to try to create a setup where one port listens for inputted text and sends it to an webpage that's listening on another port. I've tried looking through the documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_port_host_connectlistener) but it's pretty confusing to me. I've pasted the code i've written so far, but i bet it's off-base.

```
var net = require('net');
var http = require('http');

var sockets = [];

var firstCall = true;

var webpage = http.Server(function(req, res) {
  if (firstCall) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    firstCall = false;
  }
  req.on('data', function(d) {
    res.write(d);
  }
});

var inputs = net.Server(function(socket) {
  sockets.push(socket);

  socket.on('data', function(d) {

  });

  socket.on('cl', function() {
    var i = sockets.indexOf(socket);
    sockets.splice(i,1);
  });
});

inputs.listen(8080);
webpage.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use socket.io for something like this; makes life easier, here is a good assist:

https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io

Comment: I'm trying to re-do it using socket.io, but there are a bunch of new elements they use in their examples. Could you or @Yusuf maybe quickly sketch out what the socket.io code for passing something written at a given port over to another port (where there's an http server) would be?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be able to listen for the user typing text. That's done with HTML. Jquery is one way to make it easier. Maybe you have that already and didn't paste it.

Then, send your message via socket.io, where when the server receives a message, it routes it to all connected clients.